# Assist me in creating a hamburger menu for responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I created a responsive hamburger menu for my website, however, there is a button tag in the navbar that is causing an issue.

It seems to be great on a desktop view, however, the button is missing from the hamburger menu on a mobile device.

If I put the button tag under the ul, the desktop view is disrupted.

Despite the fact that it is unfinished, please assist with this issue.

**I'm including an image to give you an idea of what I'm looking for.**
[image]

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300&family=Prata&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  font-family: "Inter", "Prata", serif;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-section {
  margin: 2rem 6rem;
}

.nav-logo,
.nav-links,
.nav-button {
  font-family: "prata", sans-serif;
}

.nav-logo {
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "prata", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 0.2;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-button {
  background-color: rgb(255, 219, 74);
  color: black;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: "prata", sans-serif;
}


/* responsive menu */

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #icon {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #2f3640;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .nav-links a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  a.active,
  a:hover {
    color: #3498db;
  }
  .nav-links i {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  nav a {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-section">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <!-- Navbar Logo  -->
    <a class="nav-logo" href="#">Johnathan Specter</a>

    <!-- Navbar Links  -->
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Chats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Awards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Navbar Button  -->
    <button class="nav-button">Get in touch</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's not apparent where you're having trouble from what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **@media** css rule for different screen widths.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Many ways to approach it.

The trick sometimes is to make 2 menus.
One shown on pc and one for mobile.

You could also use JS if youre familiar with it.

**codepen** is a good place to try out examples.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether to place the button within or outside the ul tag; if I keep it inside, there's an issue in desktop view, and if I keep it outside, it doesn't appear in the menu in mobile mode.

Comment: you need to update the code snippets in such a way that the html and css are part of a single snippet, instead of 2 separate snippets.

OR

you could upload the code on jsfiddle.net and share that link.

PS:
I've made a fiddle with the code youve posted:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/mellowmonk/h9fdacjt/1/)

Comment: Please see [answer]. This isn't a complete solution. Also, [never link "link"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/).